# Can't click item with Selenium - Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

So I had this script that was functioning alright and then stoped working.
The item doesn't get clicked when I run the script and appears this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/6ko/Desktop/CodePython/katas/kata3.py", line 47, in <module>
   actions.perform()
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 80, in perform
   self.w3c_actions.perform()
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/action_builder.py", line 76, in perform
   self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
   self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds
```

This is my code:

```
edu = driver.find_element_by_id("118735")
ActionChains(driver).click(edu).perform()
```

This is the site's element code:

```
    <div class="tnt-item" style="cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto;" id="118735">
                  <div class="song" style="opacity: 1;">
                    <div class="position">17</div>
                    <div class="song-cover" style="position:relative;"><img class="img-fluid" src="/upload/album/00000036404.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="song-info">
                      <div class="song-name">Love You Better</div>
                      <div class="song-artists"><span title="Edu Monteiro">Edu Monteiro</span></div>
                      <div class="tnt-listen-music">
                        <div class="audioPlayer sm2-bar-ui small">
                          <div class="bd sm2-main-controls">
                            <div class="sm2-inline-element sm2-button-element">
                              <div class="sm2-button-bd"><a class="sm2-inline-button play-pause tm-30sec-listen" href="#play" id="TNT">
                            Play / pause</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sm2-inline-element sm2-inline-status">
                              <div class="sm2-playlist">
                                <div class="sm2-playlist-target"><ul class="sm2-playlist-bd"><li></li></ul></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="sm2-progress">
                                <div class="sm2-progress-bd">
                                  <div class="sm2-progress-track">
                                    <div class="sm2-progress-bar"></div>
                                    <div class="sm2-progress-ball">
                                      <div class="icon-overlay"></div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sm2-inline-time">0:00</div>
                                <div class="sm2-inline-duration">0:00</div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="bd sm2-playlist-drawer sm2-element">
                            <div class="sm2-playlist-wrapper">
                              <ul class="sm2-playlist-bd">
                                <li class="selected"><a id="" class="norewrite exclude button-exclude inline-exclude audiofile" style="font-size:0px;" isexclusiveplay="true" isclip="true" href="9x4h6qd1-48y7-5fxt-q5ll-dknvbm4r42f5.mp4"></a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="song-check"><input type="checkbox" name="tnt-vote" class="tnt-vote" style="pointer-events:none;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Can you help me please? Already searched similar problems but can't find a solution to my problem.
Thank you so much for your time!

(the script is to vote in a music, this is the website https://radiocomercial.iol.pt/programas/tnt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try moving to the element first?

```
edu = driver.find_element_by_id("118735")
try:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(edu).perform()
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception :", str(e))
#edu.click() selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", edu)
```

Comment: I tried it and it gave me this error:  `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (600, 3505)` 

Does this mean the item I'm trying to click is unclickable?

Comment: @6ko I updated the answer to try clicking the element using javascript instead.

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much for your time!! Really appreciated :))